# Pandas - Filling each rows of one Dataframe with value from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes one with set of dates (df1) and another with set of emp_ids (df2). I am trying to create a new Dataframe such that every emp_id in df2 is tagged to every date in df1.

Given below is how my Dataframe look like

df1

```
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
2018-01-04
```

df2

```
emp_1
emp_2
emp_3
```

Expected output:

```
2018-01-01,emp_1
2018-01-02,emp_1
2018-01-03,emp_1
2018-01-04,emp_1
2018-01-01,emp_2
2018-01-02,emp_2
2018-01-03,emp_2
2018-01-04,emp_2
2018-01-01,emp_3
2018-01-02,emp_3
2018-01-03,emp_3
2018-01-04,emp_3
```

I converted the date column to a string and tried doing the below but it returned an empty Dataframe

I tried doing `pd.merge(df1, df2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called `carthesian product`. In `pandas` you can do it that way:

```
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0

result = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').drop('key',axis= 1)
```

**Edit :** to proove it works

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04'],columns=['date'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['emp_1','emp_2','emp_3'],columns=['id'])

# res
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0

res = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').drop('key',axis= 1)

# print
print(res.sort_values('id'))
```

Console :

```
    date        id
0   2018-01-01  emp_1
3   2018-01-02  emp_1
6   2018-01-03  emp_1
9   2018-01-04  emp_1
1   2018-01-01  emp_2
4   2018-01-02  emp_2
7   2018-01-03  emp_2
10  2018-01-04  emp_2
2   2018-01-01  emp_3
5   2018-01-02  emp_3
8   2018-01-03  emp_3
11  2018-01-04  emp_3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. That did help but I am seeing for a few dates the new record does not get created. I have converted all dates to a string and then performed the above merge. But I am not sure why for a few dates the new row does not get created..